# How do I input 5 numbers and check if they are odd or even in C

Tags: c

I am able to check if one number is odd or even but how do I do it with 5 numbers? Not exactly sure how I should do that. I tried to do it with 5 but it didn't work.

[image]

(picture where I try to do five ones)

[image]

(the picture with one integer)

Comment: Try using a `for` loop.

Comment: What does not work? You posted tweice the same code.

Comment: If you want to scan 5 parameters, use 5 format specifiers, not 2. And please please please, never ever post images of code. Copy&Paste the code as text instead.

Comment: Your code won't compile. You are using `number` and it's not declared

Comment: You can read the five parameters into an array first. Then use a for loop to check each element of the array for checking if it is odd.

Answer (score 0):

*how do i do it with 5 numbers ?*  One way to do this is to use `for/while` loop & inside loop scan integer number every time & check whether it even or odd. For e.g

```
int number = 0;/* initialize with 0 */
for(int row = 0 ; row < 5;row++) {
        printf("Enter an integer \n");
        scanf("%d",&number); /* scan every time */
        if(number % 2 == 0 ) {
                printf("%d is even \n",number);
        }
        else {
                printf("%d is odd \n",number);
        }
}
```

Or it's better to use **array**. Declare an *array of 5 integers* & do the required operation with array. For e.g

```
int number[5]; /* array of 5 int elements */
int ele = sizeof(number)/sizeof(number[0]);
for(int row = 0 ; row < ele;row++) {
        printf("Enter an integer \n");
        scanf("%d",&number[row]); /* scan every time */
        if(number[row] % 2 == 0 ) {
                printf("%d is even \n",number[row]);
        }
        else {
                printf("%d is odd \n",number[row]);
        }
}
```

Also to check whether given number is even or odd you can use **bitwise** operator. For e.g  In above loop

```
(number[row] & 1) ? printf("%d is odd \n",number[row]) : printf("%d is even \n",number[row]) ;
```

Comment: If you're doing the odd/even check in the loop, there is no need for an array.   The only firm justification for an array would be that some subsequent code needs to have access to all the entered values, which is untrue both of the question and your sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't go through the image what you have posted in the question. As you noted already attached image to the SO question is not encouraged, you got the downvote for that. I didn't go through the image.

It's very simple to identify the provided int array is even or odd. You need a loop in order to do this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

    int size = 4;
    int number[size];
    int i;

    printf("Enter an integer: ");

    //Taking in an int from stdin  
    for (i=0; i < size; i++)
        scanf("%d", &number[i]);

    //Checking the number is even or odd
    for (i=0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d: %s ", number[i], (number[i] % 2) ?"odd":"even");


    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
./a.out 
Enter an integer: 2
4
5
8
2:even 4:even 5:odd 8:even
```

Comment: Nice answers, I couldnt post my code so I had to post it as a image, I wasn't sure what the issue with my code was, maybe I didnt have the perfect spaces between the lines or curly brackets or something like that but I have no idea why my code wasn't "correct"

Comment: @Lordkaxan, you can copy paste the code from your editor. Its because the code needs to highlight so that it wont show as the plain text file, How to hightligh the code in question, first select the code and press `ctrl +k` so that the pasted code would get highlighted. If not someone might have helped you in editing your question.

Comment: Improve the statement in the for loop to:`printf("%d: %s ", number[i], (number[i] % 2) ?"odd":"even");`

Answer (score 0):

You can either

-Use an array to store the numbers and display if they are odd or even after input all of them

```
int i;
int *num;
num = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
i = 0;

while (i < 5)
{
    printf("Enter an integer\n");
    scanf("%d", &num[i++]);
}
i = 0;
while (i < 5)
    printf("%d is %s\n", num[i++], ((num[i] % 2 == 0) ? ("odd") : ("even")));
free(num);
```

-Show the result just after inputing, as you did

```
int i;
int num;
i = 0;

while (i < 5)
{
    printf("Enter an integer\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("%d is %s\n", num, ((num % 2 == 0) ? ("odd") : ("even")));
}
```

Long time I haven't wrote some C, there might be silly things.